# Understanding the Pinterest's way of implementing facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I did `InspectElement` on Pinterest's facebook login button, I saw this:

```
<a href="/facebook/register/?scope=email,user_likes,user_birthday,publish_actions" class="BigButton facebook" data-network="facebook" data-callback-url="/facebook/register/">
              <span class="logo"></span>
              Facebook
            </a>
```

I could not found anything related to calling Facebook JS SDK with APP_ID, setting cookie, session etc.
How is it implemented here? What are `data-network` and `data-callback-url` tags? Are they custom tags developed by Pinterest's developers?
How can implement with the same cleaner approach?

Answer (score 1):

Pinterest is using server-side login. Hence, you will not find FB's client-side JS SDK based FB.login calls. However, they seem to be using the JS SDK for getting login status and that's why they have FB.init calls.

These 'data-' attributes are part of HTML5. A quick search will help you with documents on how to use it with JS/JQuery and how it simplifies the code. In their case, they are using the values for 'network' and 'callback-url' in JS to handle something (I don't see the code that you mention above to comment further).